# How to properly display message between sender and receiver in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get chat message between **ann** and **john**. They have two messages, hello1 and hello2.

I have implemented the code below but only the first message `hello 1` is displayed. What can I try next?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>

   </head>
   <body>
<script src="build/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/babel">


function Application(){
const chat = {"results": 
[
{"sender_name": "ann", "reciever_name": "john", "message": "hello 1"},
{"sender_name": "john", "reciever_name": "ann", "message": "hello 2"},

{"sender_name": "john", "reciever_name": "frank", "message": "message to frank"},
{"sender_name": "frank", "reciever_name": "john", "message": "message to john"},
{"sender_name": "frank", "reciever_name": "mark", "message": "message to mark"},

]};

//const ok =chat.results.length;
//alert(ok);



const sender_name1 ="ann";
const sender_name2 = "john";

const reciever_name1 ="ann";
const reciever_name2 = "john";

const record = chat.results.filter(rec => 
(rec.sender_name === sender_name1  && rec.reciever_name === sender_name2) 
&& 
(rec.sender_name === reciever_name1  && rec.reciever_name === reciever_name2) );



return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <ul>

<h1> Chat Message</h1>


{/*
            {chat.results.map((obj, i) => (
*/}
             {record.map((obj, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
                {obj.message}


              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );

  }

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work

```js
const chat = {
  results: [
    {
      sender_name: 'ann',
      reciever_name: 'john',
      message: 'hello 1',
    },
    {
      sender_name: 'john',
      reciever_name: 'ann',
      message: 'hello 2',
    },

    {
      sender_name: 'john',
      reciever_name: 'frank',
      message: 'message to frank',
    },
    {
      sender_name: 'frank',
      reciever_name: 'john',
      message: 'message to john',
    },
    {
      sender_name: 'frank',
      reciever_name: 'mark',
      message: 'message to mark',
    },
  ],
};

const sender_name1 = 'ann';
const sender_name2 = 'john';

const reciever_name1 = 'ann';//swapped these
const reciever_name2 = 'john';

const record = chat.results.filter(
  (rec) =>//changed this
    (rec.sender_name === sender_name1 &&
      rec.reciever_name === sender_name2) ||
    (rec.sender_name === reciever_name2 &&
      rec.reciever_name === reciever_name1)
);

console.log(record);
```